# Setting Background Color Of Button in WPF on runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, database, button, background

I am trying to set Background Color of Button(Names: b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9) in WPF on runtime.

Color Name is getting from Database that is Red right now. But it's giving me System.NullReferenceExceptionn: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
private void ButtonBgColor()
{
string qryBgColor = "select Name from lookup where code in (select VALUE from qSettings where name='BUTTON_BG_COLOR') and type='BgColor'";
try
{
sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(qryBgColor, sqlConnection);
sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (sqlDataReader.Read())
{
string BUTTON_BG_COLOR = sqlDataReader["Name"].ToString();
Button[] b = new Button[9];
for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
{
var textBlock08 = (TextBlock)b[i].Template.FindName("myTextBlock", b[i]);
textBlock08.Background = (System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush)new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(BUTTON_BG_COLOR);
}
}
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString(), "Button Background Color Exception");
}
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't assigned anything to b. It's just an empty array. Therefore, calling b[i] will always result in a null-ref.

Comment: it's in Loop, how it could be NULL?

Comment: Your array is not null, but each element inside the array is null.

Comment: b0 is name of button

Comment: var textBlock08 = (TextBlock)b[i].Template.FindName("myTextBlock", b[i]);

this line of code references the b array, in which every item is null. that is what I am saying.

Comment: so how could i resolve this problem ?

Comment: I would revisit the fundamentals of developing applications using WPF.